# Does it 'break' MVC to have information about a model in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and I have a question concerning my view.

I have a strongly typed view:

```
@model CellularAutomata.Models.D1CellularAutomata
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}
<h2>View</h2>

<table>
@foreach (CellularAutomata.Models.Grid grid in Model.GridHistory){ 
    <tr>
        @foreach (CellularAutomata.Models.Cell cell in grid.Cells[0]){
            if (cell.State == CellularAutomata.Models.State.On){
                <td>X</td>
            }
            if (cell.State == CellularAutomata.Models.State.Off){
                <td>O</td>
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Does it break the rules of MVC to reference parts of the model in my view, such as

```
(CellularAutomata.Models.Cell cell in grid.Cells[0])
```

or

```
(cell.State == CellularAutomata.Models.State.On)
```

If this is incorrect, what is the best way to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all, since your view is strongly typed against your model. If your view was model agnostic then it would be a problem, but as this is a view *for* D1CellularAutomata it is appropriate to have D1CellularAutomata specific references in your view.